# Could you help me evaluate my database schema for my pet project?

Tags: schema

I'm planning to make a pet project about a shop with a cart to consolidate knowledge into practice. I'm pretty new to databases and would like to hear from you about how I can improve my data schema. I hope you understand (._.)'[image]

Comment: I like the colors.